# How to access the one component properties form other component with out binding

Tags: apache-flex, binding

I would like to bind two components ***with out binding*** and which resides in different MXML.
for eg: A.mxml has textinput and B.mxml has a combobox when choose one item in B.mxml selected item should be display in A.mxml textinput.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Listen for the Combobox's change event and in the event handler update the text property of your text input. As you have mentioned that both reside in separate mxml's, you might need to add eventlistener on (common) parent to both.

Answer (score 0):

"Flex in a week" on day 3 of traing has some good information on extending the event class.

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/videotraining.html

Extending the event class for the "change" event would be an easy way to handle this.